# Ember.js use itemController if not following naming Conventions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

According to official documentation, way to create itemcontroller is:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
itemController: 'post'
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // the `title` property will be proxied to the underlying post.
  titleLength: function() {
    return this.get('title').length;
  }.property('title')
});
```

But I'm not setting my ArrayController to App. It is set to a local variable behind a function scope. And the itemController property can only be string (according to documentation). So how do I set the itemController property?

My code looks like this:

```
var Channels=Ember.Object.extend({
        list:Ember.ArrayController.create(
            {
                "model":[
                    {
                        "id":"display",
                        "label":"Display",
                    },{
                        "id":"social",
                        "label":"Social",
                    },{
                        "id":"email",
                        "label":"Email",
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
    });
    App.ChannelController=Ember.Controller.extend({
        channels:Channels,
    }));

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='channel'>
        <div>
            {{#each channel in channels.list}}
                {{channel.label}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

I don't want to pollute App namespace with itemControllers that is to be used locally.

**Update**

Suppose my channels is like this:

```
var Channels=Ember.Object.extend({
        list:Ember.ArrayController.create(
            {
                "model":[
                    {
                        "id":"display",
                        "label":"Display",
                    },{
                        "id":"social",
                        "label":"Social",
                    },{
                        "id":"email",
                        "label":"Email",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ),
        selected:"display"
    });
```

and I want to something like this in template:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='channel'>
        <h1>{{channels.selected}}</h1>
        <div>
            {{#each channel in channels.list}}
                <div {{bind-attr class="channel.isselected:active:inactive"}}>{{channel.label}}</div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

so that it outputs:

```
    <h1>display</h1>
    <div>
        <div class="active">Display</div>
        <div class="inactive">Social</div>
        <div class="inactive">Email</div> 
    </div>
```

How do I do it with components?

Comment: item controllers are deprecated, use components instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to read the [guide of components](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/components/) to get the full picture, but the gist of it is that you want to replace all item controllers with components. However, components will also replace the template inside of the `each` block as well. I don't entirely understand what's going on in your code, but here's an example roughly based on your code.

```
// Component
App.ChannelDisplayComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    channel: null,

    isSelected: function() {
        // Compute this however you want
        // Maybe you need to pass in another property
    }.property('channel')

});

{{! Component Template }}
<div {{bind-attr class="channel.isSelected:active:inactive"}}>
    {{channel.label}}
</div>

{{!Channels Template}}
{{#each channel in channels.list}}
    {{channel-component channel=channel}}
{{/each}}
```

The component is essentially your item controller, only it gets its own template as well.

---

You really shouldn't be worried about polluting the app namespace (unless you're having naming collisions, but that's a different issue). And as Kitler said, you should move to components instead of item controllers. But if you want to do this, the best way I can think of is overridding the (private) [controllerAt](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.4/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/array_controller.js#L242) hook.

```
var ItemController = Ember.Controller.extend({});

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    controllerAt: function(idx, object, controllerClass) {
        var subControllers = this._subControllers;
        if (subControllers.length > idx) {
            if (subControllers[idx]) {
                return subControllers[idx];
            }
        }

        var parentController = (this._isVirtual ? this.get('parentController') : this);

        var controller = ItemController.create({
            target: parentController,
            parentController: parentController,
            model: object
        });

        subControllers[idx] = controller;

        return controller;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you try answering the updated question? since you said I should move to components, I was wondering how to make it work with components.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You'll likely want to read the guide on linked to to really understand components.

Comment: {{channel-component channel=channel selected=channels.selected}}

and 

isSelected: function() {
       return this.channel.id===this.selected
    }.property('channel')

should work. thanks.